# Distinguishing two distributions with f-divergence

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics

The statistical distance (SD) has been widely used as a 'measure' of the closeness of two distributions $D_1$ and $D_1$.
Suppose that the statistical distance (here, total variation with $\ell_1$ norm) between distributions $D_1$ and $D_2$ is less than $s$. Then, as I know, there is a polynomial-time algorithm to distinguish from $D_1$ to $D_2$ whenever we have $O(s^2)$ samples.

On the other hand, as an alternative measure of closeness measure of distributions, $f$-divergence was proposed. (I am particularly interested in Renyi divergence which is a somewhat generalization of KL divergence)
If f-divergence of $D_1$ and $D_2$ is smaller than $t$, then how many samples are required to distinguish such distributions? and how to distinguish them?
Please let me know any references.